# Box webhooks deprecated in favor of long polling?

Tags: box-api

The developer [docs](https://developers.box.com/docs/#events) for Events do not mention [webhooks](http://developers.box.com/webhooks/) at all. Are they being phased out in favor of long polling for events or can we still use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are still a valid way to integrate with Box.  The link you provide is the current documentation for it.  I'll see if we can get a couple pointers to that webhooks documentation put into the relevant places on the rest of the docs.