# Getting rename event from Box webhook, also are events preferred to webhook in Box?

Tags: box-api

I'm trying to use webhooks to get notifications for changes in a user's Box account.  One thing I don't see is an option to get a webhook notification when an item is renamed. Is it possible to get a notification for rename?  I see that RENAME is available via the event API, is it preferable to use the event API?  I saw another stackoverflow question asking about webhook vs event ([Box webhooks deprecated in favor of long polling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320795/box-webhooks-deprecated-in-favor-of-long-polling)) and the answer said webhooks are still valid, but didn't really comment on webhook vs event.

I'd prefer webhooks since they are a close fit to how I get changes for Dropbox accounts but it appears from the docs that event has more information/options. Also, it seems it's possible to miss a Box webhook notification which could create an inconsistent state between Box the model in my application.

Which to choose?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to get a WebHook notification when an item is renamed.

The choice between WebHooks and events really depends on what you're building. WebHooks are generally easier to use, but the events stream can give you more power. In your case, you'll probably need to use events so you can be notified of a renames.

It's also worth noting that if your application really depends on staying in sync with the state of Box, you're better off using the events stream. It lets you specify a last known position in the stream so that you can catch up on any missed events if your application goes offline.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I agree with your comments and came to the conclusion that I need to do  long polling for events.  It turns out Dropbox offers long polling as well so I can make my application more consistent between Dropbox and Box